# How to know which JCheckBox sent ItemEvent

Tags: java, swing, events, checkbox

I have a number of checkboxes in my Swing Project. For each checkbox select/deselect a particular query is to be executed. I know one way of getting the source of checkbox is

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)  {
if(e.getSource=="checkbox object")
{ 
some code goes here; 
}
}
```

If i have small number of checkboxes than this solution is best but if i have many checkboxes then i have to write lengthy code. Is there a way to find the object of  checkbox that causes the event in a single command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get selected checkbox by like this

```
JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Check1");
 JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("Check2");
 checkBox1.setName("Check1");
 checkBox2.setName("Check2");
 ItemListener listener = new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();
         String name = check.getName();
         System.out.println(name);
    }
};
checkBox1.addItemListener(listener);
checkBox2.addItemListener(listener);
```

Comment: I am getting output as "null".

Comment: @RohanKandwal forgot to setName to the check box. checkBox1.setName("Check1"); updated now. Or you can use `check.getText()`

Comment: checkBox1.setName("Check1"); did the trick but is it possible to get checkbox object such as "checkBox1" as output?

Comment: @RohanKandwal Change the name to suit your needs

Comment: This is quite a good solution if you can put enough information into the checkbox name string to process the click.

Comment: to get checkbox object such as "checkBox1" as output you need to subClass JCheckBox and overwrite toString method.

Answer (score 1):

If you handle checks in some verry uniform way, it may help to put `JChekBox`es into `HashMap`, mapping them into some structure (maybe data source or some processing object) that helps to process the event easier. Amount of code can be further reduced by having a method that creates, adds and registers a checkbox. The general idea would be along the lines

```
HashMap<JCheckBox, String> urls = new HashMap<JCheckBox, String>();   
    // Here I use String but can be any complex data structure.

ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String url = urls.get(e.getSource());
                    // Work with the selected URL now
    }
};

void buildCheckBoxes() {
    register("http://wikipedia.org");
    register("http://stackoverflow.com");
            // and 101 others, or load the list from the file.
}

void register(String url) {
    JCheckBox box = new JCheckBox("Use "+url);
    urls.put(box, url);
    box.addActionListener(listener);
             // One listener for all, defined above
    myPanel.add(box);
            // Some panel probably with GridLayout
}
```

From the other side, if your actions are very different, it may also be better to have a separate listener (probably inner or anonymous class) for each different action:

```
    JCheckBox boxA = new JCheckBox("A");
    JCheckBox boxB = new JCheckBox("B");

boxA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // Only code for boxA
    }
});

boxB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // Only code for boxB
    }
});
```

As soon as there is more code in the listener, you should move it into a method on you main class.

Comment: I am still a noob and learning the basics so i am unaware of such deep coding

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which component (either CheckBox or any other Component) has generated an event in java, you can assign name to that component using "setName(name)" method.

```
// For CheckBox
JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox();
checkBox1.setName("CheckBox1");

// Any other Component
JButton button1 = new JButton();
button1.setName("Button1");
```

Now in listener class you can obtain source object who has generated current event.

```
// CheckBox Listener
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)  
{
    JCheckBox source = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();

    if(source.getName().equals("CheckBox1"))
    { 
        //some code goes here; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the way of using equals, I already said that this way will result in a longer code if we are using too many checkboxes. I want a code to get the object of checkbox such as "checkBox1" as output.

Comment: Switch statement can be used with strings in Java 1.7.

Comment: If you are going to use single listener for multiple components then you are going to have checks to identify source component. You can write it in **itemStateChanged** method or in some other method/class but at the end you are going to write it somewhere. If you want to avoid checks, then best practice is to write separate listeners for each component. That way your code becomes simple and short as you are not going to have checks to identify source.

Comment: Switch statements will also take too many lines of coding solution by @vels4j is almost what i need but that code too need use of setName() function.