# Getting name of JComponent and assigning as parameter in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, prepared-statement

Okay, so this is what I have so far and it works. However, I'm not able to specify to which `?` (or `parameter`) the `int 1` or `0` (`boolean` converted to `int`) is set (through `setInt()`). I tried using the `getName()` to see the component `variable name` but it returns `null` when I print it.

1. How can I assign a checkbox's value as parameter to my PreparedStatement if I'm not able to specify correctly on which textbox the value of 1 or 0 is from?

   `ps.setInt(1,valueOfUnknownCheckbox);` `//need to put the correct checkbox as 2nd argument.`
2. I saw some information about using `Java Reflection` which I'm totally unfamiliar with. Is there any way without using `Java Reflection`?

Some of the checkbox values are not going to the correct database table's column.

I hope you can help with me guys. I wanted to be able to use `List` to collect components from containers to lessen the lines of codes.

Here's my code.

```
private void saveAdminPermissions(){
    List<Component> adminPermissionsChbxs = fm.getComponentsAsList(administrationPermissionsCheckBoxPanel);

    Boolean bool = null;

    String updateSQL = 
            "UPDATE allusers_admin_permissions SET CURC_BTN=?, DISCOUNTS_BTN=?, SECTIONS_BTN=?,"
            + " USERS_BTN=?, SCHEDULING_BTN=?, YRLEVELS_BTN=?, ACCTG_BTN=? WHERE USERID=? ";
    try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateSQL);)
    {
        int x=1;
        for(Component c : adminPermissionsChbxs){
            if(c instanceof JCheckBox){
               bool = ( (JCheckBox)c ).isSelected(); 
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Name: "+ ((JCheckBox)c).getName() );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,bool);
            } //--end of if
            int boolToInt = (bool)?1:0 ;
            ps.setInt(x, boolToInt);
            x++;
        }//--end of forloop
            ps.setInt(8, um.getIdOfSelected(usersList));
            ps.executeUpdate(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update successful");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error@saveAdminPermissions\n"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}//--end of method
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333026/how-to-know-which-jcheckbox-sent-itemevent.

Comment: By any chance, are your check boxes in a `JTable`?

Comment: @trashgod No, I just put them inside a JPanel. Not yet familiar with JTables but I started studying it.

Comment: @p3ace: My error; I've updated my original answer to discuss both possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches are possible:

- Instead of looping though view components, create a permission model having a collection of states such as `List<Boolean>`. As shown in [*How to Use Check Boxes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox), let each `JCheckBox` have an `ItemListener` that updates its `Boolean` value in the `List`; an example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883541/230513). Use the list in constructing your `PreparedStatement`.
- Alternatively, store the permission description and state in a suitable [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), and use a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as the view. As described in [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), the default renderer/editor for a model value of type `Boolean` is a check box. Neither the renderer nor editor remember the value between calls to render or edit a cell's value, but the table underlying `TableModel` *must* do so. Some guidelines and a typical example are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062055/230513). You should be able to invoke the table's `getValueAt()` method to find the current setting of the desired cell in a particular row and column, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

Comment: How is this relevant to the OP's question? He was interested in a JCheckBox, not a JTable.